# Laravel and vue, auto login after registration using JWT

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuex

I am developing a project with vue as frontend and laravel 8 api. I am using JWT for authentication. I understand a token has to be generated before a user can login, but is there a way to automatically log in the user after they register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the token after the user was registered succesfully:

```php
/*This is your register function, this is after you succesfully saved the user in the database. 
Remember to use JWTAuth*/

/*YOUR REGISTER LOGIC HERE, THEN*/

if($user->save()){
    $credentials = ["email"=>$user->email,"password"=>password_from_request];
    try{
        if(JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
           return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }
    }
    catch (JWTException $e) {
      // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => $e], 500);
    }
}else 
    return $this->userRegisterFailedResponse();
    /*Your custom response in case the register fails*/
```

You can check the implementation of the respondWithToken function at the [JWT documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/)